# read two files, one raw and the other json

Tags: jq

I have two files.  The first is a dnsmasq.leases file, text only.  I can read this file using the -R switch.  I have another file, macs.json, this file contains a json dictionary with mac address information in it.  What I'd like to do is read these two files from jq cli using

```
jq -s raw:dnsmasq.leases macs.json
```

I can decompose it, and do it in stages, like:

```
jq -Rs '.|split("\n")' dnsmasq.leases | jq -s '.[0] as $macs|.[1] as $leases|etc' macs.json -
```

but I wondered if there was a way to read one raw and the other json at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can always read a raw file using the `--rawfile VAR FILENAME` command-line option.